# What sort of entity do strings convert into when embedded in spacetime? or What do strings represent?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, branes, string-field-theory

I hope someone can help with this question with some open mind.
I know there has been close questions, but I have read them and they do not target the same spot I do.

In the [worldline formalism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/worldline+formalism) of QFT, Quantum particles are assumed to be as fundamental objects of reality living on the intrinsic space of the worldline. But this turn out to be equivalent to quantum fields living in/on a $3+1$ dimensional Minkowski background.

In string theory, the world-volume formulation is quite central and there the fundamental objects are assumed to be the quantum strings (branes etc).

My question is, what are the equivalent quantum objects living on higher dimensional background spacetime?

Should they represent the Gravitational field? But isn't this contradictory as gravitational field is itself the background?

If not the gravitational field, what do they represent in the higher dimensional embedding spacetime? Anything similar to fields? Is there any mathematical candidate for such entity? Any lagrangian in the embedding spacetime and not the worldsheet?

Comment: Lookup string field theory

Comment: Nice. I looked up the wiki page. There seems to be significant differences with QFT(as I know it). BRST quantization and then second quantization? Is there at least a parallel to this approach in QFT for fields? In QFT there's only one quantization afaik. Can one do the same to the worldline formalism of QFT? Moreover It seems the field content of the proposed BRST wave function is infinite, meaning it contains an infinite number of different spin fields with different masses. But this is not the case in QFT. Worldline of a photon leads to a unique vector field. @ConnorBehan

Comment: Even more, from what I know of in traditional Kaluza-Klein mechanism, in the higher dimensional space, there's only gravity, i.e. Spin 2 field. But it's not the case here. @ConnorBehan